# Why do neural network weights have to be between 0 and 1?

Tags: neural-networks, weights, artificial-neuron

I've been reading about neural networks for a long time, and I saw that in each one, the weights are always between 0 and 1. Why is this? I tried programming one, but the sigmoid function just seemed like one more thing to make it more complicated, without need. Why couldn't the range of a weight or neuron value be infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the weights between 0 and 1 helps accelerate learning. They do not have to be between 0 and 1.
Typically the weights get normalized to [-1, 1]. But it also depends on your problem.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence for the claim "Having the weights between 0 and 1 helps accelerate learning."? Have you observed this empirically? If yes, it might be a good idea to provide the link to such an experiment. If you have seen this written in a research paper or book, cite it.